# How do I know what objects in a scene are linked? And how do I find their file locations on my computer?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data, scene

I have a scene/animation that contains a bunch of linked-in objects from other files. My folder with my objects accidentally got duplicated to another area on my computer (i.e.: one in a "3D ART" Folder and one on my desktop). I want to delete the extra folder, but because the names of the objects are the same, I am worried some may have gotten linked to the extra folder. I want to check before I delete the folder, so I don't lose my work. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi :). You can rename the folder (so the links are broken), then reload the file and check for missing files

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of methods to find that,

1. In the outliner
2. The Info view
3. The terminal

---

1.- The Outliner

Here you can see the Outliner of a basic scene with a linked asset
[image: Default Outliner]

If you change the view of the outliner to `Blender File` here
[image: Outliner View]

You will see all the contents of the current .blend opened, and in the bottom of the list the relative (showed in the image) or absolute paths to the files linked

[image: Outliner Blender file View]

---

2.- The Info view/panel

When you load the .blend file you will see all the paths of the linked files here in absolute and relative paths ****Note:** *This view will start to get filled with all important messages, warnings and errors as you work on the file, so better check this view on file load***
[image: Info view]

---

3.- The terminal

If you open the terminal

[image]

You will see something like the past option but with additional debug messages and things like that, so like the info view better check on startup and file load.
[image]

Comment: Additionally my personal favorite for a quick overview via Object Properties > Browse. Linked objects marked with 'L' (old) or Icon (new).